# What Linux OS's come with Linux Kernel 2.6.32

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

wasn't too sure where to ask this. I am just trying to find which Linux OS's or past OS's had the Linux Kernel 2.6.32. Just need to know for compatibility issues with some modules I am working on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Honestly don't see how this is off topic..as this has to do with programming compatibility between different OSs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debian squeeze currently uses this kernel.